# Requesting partial view via ajax in forms authenticated application

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, partial-views

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with forms authentication enabled. I'd like to request a partial view using ajax and load the resulting html into a div on my main view, but I want to make sure that the ajax request is an authenticated request.

Is passing the authentication cookie in the ajax request for the partial view common practice to validate such requests and if so how would one go about acquiring the authentication cookie while on the client and then sending it along with the ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the authentication-attribute on your action-method and it will be sent correctly:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult GetPartial(){
    return PartialView();
}
```

It is common to just pass the cookie with an Ajax-call. From the server's point of view, an ajax-call is not different from any other call.

Comment: Yes, but how would one go about acquiring the authentication cookie while on the client and then sending it along with the ajax request?

Comment: The cookie should automatically be included